# Python regular expression to remove "problem=None," from "Abc(problem=None, fds=5, sff=(2, 1, 0))"

Tags: python, regex

I've got a  python string

```
s = "Abc(problem=None, fds=5, sff=(2, 1, 0))"
s2 = "Abc(problem=None)"
```

What I want to do is remove the "problem=None, "

So it'll looks like

```
s = "Abc(fds=5, sff=(2, 1, 0))"
s2 = "Abc()"
```

Please mind the ','

How to achieve this? Thanks very much!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing *all* syntactically valid whitespace:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r"\s*problem\s*=\s*None\s*,?\s*", "", "abc( problem = None , )")
'abc()'
>>> re.sub(r"\s*problem\s*=\s*None\s*,?\s*", "", "abc( problem = None  )")
'abc()'
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

A regex that will work in both cases is:

```
/problem=None,?\s*/
```

The ? makes the comma optional and the \s* will strip any trailing whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

```
re.sub(r"problem=None,? +", "", s)
```

Comment: Like the comma, the trailing whitespace is optional, but your regex requires at least one space character to be present.  You should use `*` instead of `+`, like the other responders did.

Comment: The OP was asking for removing a string with one space after the comma, making my RE work, albeit with the problem that I'll remove more than they asked for.. In the general case I agree with you though.  Thanks for fixing the formatting, I was answering from a device that doesn't play as nice as it could.